# Does nvidia gpu work less efficiently when it is the only gpu in PC?

Tags: cuda

I want to assemble a new computer mainly for CUDA applications. When it comes to CPU I have to choose between AMD and Intel.
Most of the AMD's processors don't have integrated gpu while Intel's processors do.

My question is:

If the nvidia gpu would be the only graphic processing unit in the whole PC (without integrated one),
would its efficiency for CUDA programs be worse as it has to produce some graphics on a desktop (while using for example Matlab)?

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Yes, a GPU that is shared between display tasks and CUDA tasks has significant limitations.

Comment: It could be an interesting question, if (perhaps) rephrased a bit. How much GPU resources does a Windows/Linux/... system use when performing very simple tasks (idle desktop, instance of Matlab running, ..). Or: how much slower would a CUDA application run compared to running it on the same (but dedicated for CUDA) GPU? Is it possible to give some rough numbers for that?

Comment: @Bart I'll try to check one day, and let you know here - I have the right tools and will be working on a related project soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anwer is yes, efficiency would be slightly lower due to the GPU doing display tasks, like moving the cursor around or scrolling a display in a .pdf browser.

however if you are aiming for a reasonably mid-to-high-end GPU, the loss of efficiency is marginal. If you have enough money, you will buy dedicated GPU, but if not, then just don't bother. It might be like 1% or less.

A bigger problem is that the display takes up RAM, that (a) becomes unavailable to CUDA applications and (b) the CUDA manual states that the display driver is allowed to dis-own the CUDA application from it's memory at any time without warning (!).

If you ask me if that does really happen (display driver taking over the CUDA app memory), then yes, I have experienced it, with the prime example being when you change the resolution of your display.

So definetely don't do any banking with GPUs or you might see your accounts being randomly infused with millions :-)

That's why 'proffesional' CUDA cards (the tesla variety) have no display outputs - just in case.